# Showing $[E_1E_2 : E_1] = [E_2 : E_1 \cap E_2]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

I'm struggling with this problem. Given $E/F$, $E_1/F$, and $E_2/F$ are field extensions such that $E_1, E_2 \leq E$ and $E_1/F$ and $E_2/F$ are finite, we want to show that $[E_1E_2:E_1] = [E_2 : E_1 \cap E_2]$. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: This can't be right. Is there additional conditions?

Comment: These are the conditions given. It's a possibility there was a typo

Comment: Read my to answers to another post, generally it should be $[E_1E_2 : E_1] [E_1 : E_1\cap E_2]=[E_1E_2 : E_2] [E_2 : E_1\cap E_2]$. There is no reason that $[E_1E_2 : E_1]=[E_2 : E_1\cap E_2]$ must be true without other conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter example:

$$E_1=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$$
$$E_2=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta_3)$$

Comment: Primitive cube root of unity.